# use same resolver for each children in the app

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7

I'm trying to use a general resolver for all my app.

In the root, I have no component, I just load a children depending on route.
I inlcude a resolver, but it's not called by my app:

```
{
path: '',
resolve: { data: AppResolver },
canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/mainView',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'menu1',
    loadChildren: 'app/menu1/menu1.module#Menu1Module'
  },
  {
    path: 'menu2',
    loadChildren: 'app/menu2/menu2.module#Menu2Module'
  }
]
},
{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

I see as AppResolver is never invoqued, is there any mistake in my app.routing file?

Comment: What is `LoggedInGaurd` returning? If it is false, then it should not be resolved.

Comment: LoggedInGuard returns true

Answer (score 0):

Each route requires its own resolver. So you could replicate the logic in this way for your requirement. Sample code below.

```
const viewRouteResolver = { data: AppResolver };
{
path: ‘’,
resolve: viewRouteResolver,
canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
children: [
   {
      path:  ‘’,
      redirectTo:  ‘/mainView’,
      pathMatch: ‘full’,
      resolver: viewRouteResolver
   },
   {
     path: ‘menu1’,
     loadChildren: ‘app/menu/menu1.module#Menu1Module’,
     resolve: viewRouteResolver
   }
 ]
}
```

so as the route gets activated owing to the path match, the resolver would be triggered.